# Convert String to java.sql.Date object in "YYYY" format

Tags: java, date-formatting, date

I want to create a java.sql.Date object of the format "YYYY". It should have only the year. I researched a lot but couldn't find a way to do it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java string to date conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216745/java-string-to-date-conversion)

Comment: You cannot. While a `java.sql.Date` pretends only to have a date it, it at least has a date, not only a year. Behind the scenes it has a point in time with millisecond presicion. That said, the class has design issues and is long outdated. Do you absolutely need one nevertheless? I’d recommend `Year` and/or `LocalDate` from java.time, the modern Java date and time API, instead. They do live up to their names and only hold what the names say. Neither of the mentioned classes can have a format in them (but `Year.toString` produces the format you seem to want).

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

Never use terrible `java.sql.Date` class, badly designed with multiple flaws.

Use either `java.time.Year` object, or an integer.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , Year.of( 2018 ) ) ;
```

…or, while using `Year` in other parts of your code:

```
myPreparedStatement.setInt( … , Year.of( 2018 ).getValue() ) ;
```

## java.time

The modern solution uses the *java.time* classes that years ago supplanted the terrible old date-time classes of `SimpleDateFormat`, `java.util.Date`, `java.sql.Date`, and so on.

The [`Year`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Year.html) class neatly represents a year value. Using this class in your code gives you type-safety and makes your code more self-documenting.

Parsing a string input.

```
Year y = Year.parse( "2018" ) ;
```

Parsing an integer input.

```
Year y = Year.of( 2018 ) ;  // Integer literal.
```

### JDBC

As of JDBC 4.2 we can directly exchange *java.time* types.

#### Exchange `Year` object

I do not know if this includes the `Year` class and `YEAR` data type in MySQL. But give it a shot. If not, make a feature request to your JDBC driver vendor to extend support. Seems like a justifiable expectation given the fact that MySQL has an explicit `YEAR` type.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , y ) ;
```

Retrieval.

```
Year y = myResultSet.getObject( … , Year.class ) ;
```

#### Exchange integer

If your JDBC driver cannot use `java.time.Year` directly, use integer.

```
myPreparedStatement.setInt( … , y.getValue() ) ;  // Pass year as an integer number.
```

Retrieval.

```
Year y = Year.of( myResultSet.getInt( … ) ) ;  // Retrieve integer, convert to `Year` object.
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: Note that JDBC 4.2 only defines support for `LocalDate`, `LocalTime`, `LocalDateTime`, `OffsetTime` and `OffsetDateTime`, all other java.time types are driver-specific extensions.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a `java.util.Date` and then convert this to a `java.sql.Date` using the constructor that takes in a `long`.

Example:

```
String year = "2018";

DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy");
java.util.Date utilDate = format.parse(year);
java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(utilDate.getTime());
```

However, it's not "only a year". Dates in Java always have a time component, so this isn't possible - it will be "1 Jan 2018 00:00:00 GMT" in my example. Is this close enough to what you want, or could you refine your question?

In addition, a `java.sql.Date` extends `java.util.Date`, so ideally you'd use the former wherever possible to satisfy the Liskov substitution principle.

Comment: Actually, I am trying to insert data into a column of type "YEAR" in a table in MySQL database using JBOSS Teiid. And in order to do this Teiid requires the data in sql date format.

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Comment: The class JavaDoc tells you to ignore the inheritance relationship between `java.util.Date` and `java.sql.Date` that resulting from a terrible hack in bad design.